# Which software to use to display postgres views for inexperienced people?

Tags: postgresql, view

I need to display database views from postgres to people who need to work with the data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), but do not need to work with the database and its logic. What kind of software I can use for this?

Comment: If your users need to do inserts, updates, and deletes, then they absolutely _do_ need to understand the logic of the database.  What is wrong with using `pgadmin`?  If you want a simpler graphical tool, then something like Squirrel SQL might make sense.

Comment: You have to think of the users as usual Excel users. This is what they worked with for years now and they are not really easily adaptable to new technologies. They basically want to keep using something like Excel, the data just comes from a database now.

Comment: try libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql then ?..

Comment: Sounds more like you want something like MS-Access, or various (usually even-worse-than-MS-Access) open source tools. If you just want a dumb tool for row manipulations search for "CRUD"